# Error moving data from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, copy, move

```
$feedback_list = array( 
    array('date1', '87586cb8b79861edcc4e6a12104b87529c53050375904ff180'), 
    array('date2', 'abc1d08c3e42cffa7eaaa84eb4fe04b44c34be497ce7e8ea26') 
);

foreach($feedback_list as $feedback) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'inactive_users' (token, username) 
       SELECT (token, username) FROM active_users WHERE token = '$feedback[1]'");
    if (!mysql_query($result,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
}
```

.. echoes the correct value, which is also present in `active_users` table, but the value is not copied to the second table. Error is:

> Error: Query was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the `mysql_query` twice. Try

```
foreach($feedback_list as $feedback) {
    $result = "INSERT INTO `inactive_users` (token, username) 
       SELECT token, username FROM active_users WHERE token = '{$feedback[1]}'";
    if (!mysql_query($result,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
}
```

Comment: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''inactive_users' (token, username) SELECT (token, username) FROM 'active' at line 1` :(

Comment: You have your table name surrounded by quotes.  Change to backticks (like my edit above) or remove them.

Comment: Ah, I thought...ok. But now `Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from your `SELECT` statement like I did above.  Didn't even see that before, that should do it.

Comment: strange, no error now but the value still does not copy to the second table.

Comment: verify your results in the `active_users` table

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
foreach($feedback_list as $feedback) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO inactive_users (token, username) SELECT token, username FROM active_users WHERE token = '{$feedback[1]}'");
}
```

Comment: `Error: Query was empty` still.

Comment: feedback is still an array, not the value (token).

Comment: @Nimbuz You're right. It should be `$feedback[1]`. But wrap it inside `{}` like my code above.

Comment: @bsdnoobz That shouldn't matter, but it's better practice.

Comment: Ohk, but new error now `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

You should never put a mysql_query inside a loop.

INSERT statements can be aggregated in to one big string.

Contrary to what I said at the beginning though, you should use the loop for your select statements, and then take the results and concatenate your insert query; performing it AFTER the loop

An example

```
$feedback_list = array( 
array('date1', '87586cb8b79861edcc4e6a12104b87529c53050375904ff180'), 
array('date2', 'abc1d08c3e42cffa7eaaa84eb4fe04b44c34be497ce7e8ea26') 
);
$insert = null;
$select = "SELECT (token, username) FROM active_users WHERE token = '%s'";
foreach($feedback_list as $feedback) {
    $sql = print_f($select, $feedback[1]);
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("SQL:$sql<br />\n". mysql_error());
    $values = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    //$values['token'] => token
    //$values['username'] => username

    $insert .= "INSERT INTO 'inactive_users' (token, username) VALUES ('{$values['token']'}','{$values['username']}')\n";
}
 $theInsert = mysql_query($insert);
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ''}'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting '}'`

Comment: '{$values['token']'}','{$values[
needs to be
'{$values['token']}','{$values[

Comment: ohk, changed, but `mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: That means the select statement failed.  Try to echo it out and make sure it is correct.